# Insert history into a new table

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on this table as shown below it has name, date,id and key. I would like to insert into new table where the old_name column maintains the change in name for that key. The output result is shown below as well. Thanks

```
           id       name        date                    Key
            1       charles     2004-05-07              1001
            2       CON         2004-05-07              1001
            3       Virginia    2006-09-08              1001
            4       MART        2012-01-03              1001
            5       McDonalds   2013-12-30              1001


    OUTPUT 

            id   old_name          name        date                 Key
            1     NULL             charles     2004-05-07           1001
            2     charles          CON         2004-05-07           1001
            3     CON              Virginia    2006-09-08           1001
            4     Virginia         MART        2012-01-03           1001
            5     MART             McDonalds   2013-12-30           1001
```

Comment: Many ways: SQL Server 2016 provides temporal tables that keep track of historical changes automatically. In previous versions you can use change tracking to detect changes. You can use a trigger that will insert records to the history table each time a row is changed

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should've been more specific. I don't want to use a trigger. I have a table and I just need to keep track of those changes and insert them into a new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a good fit for **LAG()**

```
Select id
      ,old_name = lag(name,1) over (Partition By [Key] Order by ID)
      ,name
      ,date
      ,[key]
 From YourTable
 Order By ID
```

Comment: Thanks john for your prompt response. It works just fine. It was nice to learn about lag function. Great.

Comment: @data_weed 3 things.  1) happy it helped.  2) cool name.  3) Well worth your time to get comfortable with the window functions()

Comment: Window functions like lag() are very handy, but don't forget that most of them are only available in SQL2012+. And it never hurts to read some of Mr. Ben-Gan: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lag if it is SQL Server >=2012

```
select *, lag(name,1,null) over(order by id) Old_name from #yourhistory
```

Your input table

```
create table #yourhistory (id int, name varchar(20), date date, [key] int)

insert into #yourhistory 
  ( id  ,     name   ,     date             ,       [Key] ) values
     (    1    ,'charles  ','2004-05-07',              1001   )
    ,(    2    ,'CON      ','2004-05-07',              1001   )
    ,(    3    ,'Virginia ','2006-09-08',              1001   )
    ,(    4    ,'MART     ','2012-01-03',              1001   )
    ,(    5    ,'McDonalds','2013-12-30',              1001   )
```